# Swift - swipe to delete (without tap)

Tags: swift, tableview, swipe

i have implemented:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let hide = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Verbergen") { action, index in

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        ...
        tableView.endUpdates()


    }
    hide.backgroundColor = colorWithHexString("#FC6300")

    let unhide = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Wieder\nanzeigen") { action, index in

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        ...
        tableView.endUpdates()

    }
    unhide.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Teilen") { action, index in
        ...
    }
    share.backgroundColor = colorWithHexString("#FC6300")

    if lastUsedCategory == "hidden" {
        return [unhide]
    } else if lastUsedCategory == "participated" {
        return [share]
    } else {
        return [hide]
    }
}
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // the cells you would like the actions to appear needs to be editable
    if sideBar.isSideBarOpen {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

... when i swipe, the options are shown and everything works fine.

But i want to run the actions when i swipe further (like in Mail app).

At the moment i can swipe but the option is not expanding and i have to tap the option.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?